# @babel/node@7.16.8 with express throws exception in NODE v.8

Tags: node.js, express, babel-node

Very strange problem I run into, may be someone know what problem is:
This problem observed during test in Node v.8.12.0 In Node v>14 everything is OK.  (Don't ask me why v.8 is still important.. Yes, we are still there in some apps :-(( )

Super simple app, just import, nothing else (this enough to show the problem):

```
--index.js--
import express from 'express';
```

Latest available packages for a simple app:

```
--package.json--

"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "express": "^4.17.3"
  }
```

Babel config:

```
--.babelrc--
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env"
        ]
    ],
}
```

Now complication:

`npx babel .\index.js -d dist\`  - all good, file `dist\index.js` created and `node dist\index.js` working fine.

Problem with `babel-node`:

```
> npx babel-node .\index.js

C:\xx\babelssue\node_modules\depd\index.js:252
  var file = callSite.getFileName() || '<anonymous>'
                      ^

TypeError: callSite.getFileName is not a function
    at callSiteLocation (C:\xx\babelssue\node_modules\depd\index.js:252:23)        
    at depd (C:\xx\babelssue\node_modules\depd\index.js:111:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xx\babelssue\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:14:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\xx\babelssue\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:136:24)  
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\xx\babelssue\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:141:7)    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
PS C:\xx\babelssue>
```